# Calculating the number of occurrence of specific words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string as below

I want to count the total number of occurrences of **v|** and **adv|** . I am using  the below line of code for it

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";
console.log(
  (result.split("v|").length - 1) + (result.split("adv|").length - 1)
);
```

Now technically it should be 2 i.e 1 for adv| and 1 for v| but it is actually counting the v| in the adv| as well and thus the result is 3. 
Can someone please point me what should I do to count the both as separate words?

Comment: do you need the separate count for both `adv|` and `v|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `v` section, you can have a group of two letters, which are not `ad`, to ensure that it does not match `adv|`:

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";
console.log(
  (result.split(/(?:(?!ad)..|^.?)v\|/).length-1) +
  (result.split("adv|").length-1)
);
```

https://regex101.com/r/f80iGd/1

`/(?:(?!ad)..|^.?)v\|/` means:

`(?:(?!ad)..|^.?)` - A group containing either:

`(?!ad)..` - Two letters which are not `ad`, or

`^.?` - The start of the string, or the start of the string followed by one letter

With all of the above followed by `v\|`, `v` followed by a literal `|`.

Also, rather than using `split` to construct a split array and then checking the length of the array minus one, it might be more intuitive to use `match` to match occurences of `v|` or `adv|`, and check the number of matches:

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";
console.log(
  result.match(/(?:(?!ad)..|^.?)v\|/g).length +
  result.match(/adv\|/g).length
);
```

Note that in newer Javascript environments, you can also use negative lookbehind to check that the `v` isn't preceded by `ad`:

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";
console.log(
  result.match(/(?<!ad)v\|/g).length +
  result.match(/adv\|/g).length
);
```

(above snippet may not work in all browsers)

You could also combine the two `.match` conditions into one, by using an optional group of `ad`:

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";
console.log(
  result.match(/(?:ad)?v\|/g).length
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a match starting "from the middle of a word" add `\b` at the
start of the regex (unfortunatey, JavaScript flavour of regex does not
include lookbehind) and pass it as a regex (`/.../`), not as a string
(`"..."`).

Note also that the argument of `split` is a regex and in regex `|`
has special meaning (alternative separator).
To match `|` literally, prepend it with `\`.

So the first regex should be: `/\bv\|/` and the second: `/\badv\|/`.

Comment: He's passing a `String`argument to `split`, not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first take out `adv|` and then work on `v|`. since `adv|` is the superset of `v|`.

```js
var result = "coord|and adv|then pro|it mod|may v|hurt det|the n|dog";

const advSeparated = result.split("adv|");

const totalCount = advSeparated.reduce((acc, string) =>
  acc + (string.split('v|').length - 1)
, advSeparated.length - 1)


console.log(totalCount);
```